# Registering a new user

Tags: php

I am creating a forum, I've the database, got the script for logging in existing users. However I am having a mind blank on how to create the sign up form.

I've got the sign up script and have in on a 'signup.php' page and using the method="post" and action="signupprocess.php". I understand that I need to use POST but can anybody point me in the right direction as to what I should be including in the signuprocess.php to insert the data into the database.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What information does your log in script needs from your users to log them in? thats what you put on your form

Comment: Have a look [**here**](http://www.google.com) and then come back when you have some code.

Comment: Have a look here lol @TheBlueDog. Just post then securely insert into the database....

Comment: There are numerous open source forums available to download. You appear too inexperienced to create your own.

Comment: Thought this would be a waste of time, deleted my answer after finishing it; good things come to those who wait, good things removed from those who won't.

Comment: I should have put some code in for explanation, I am sorry - my mistake. However I would like to say that I thought this was an outlet to gain help and assistance. 

I haven't asked you to write my code just point me in the right direction - if you don't have anything valuable to say then don't bother writing it. A simple, this is too vague would have sufficed.
Yes, good things come to those who wait, but if it was a waste of your time writing the answer surely it was a bigger waste of time deleting and writing your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, please try to include more details into your question and conduct a bit more research as this is a relatively easy answer to find out for yourself.

If you are using a SQL database you should be triggering a SQL QUERY whenever the Sign Up button is pressed -- assuming that all credentials are correct and valid. Usually the SQL query will look similar to this:

> $db->query("INSERT INTO signupcredentials VALUES ('John', 'Miller',
>   'jmiller@gmail.com')"

This is used in an example where a table called signupcredentials has been created with columns for First Name, LastName, and Email.

Now if you're using a PHP array to store all your values (this is not recommended for login credentials) you should be adding to the array by retrieving from the $POST variables.

It seems like you're relatively new to this so I recommend researching on various forums on how to connect/create SQL Databases or adding to PHP arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You pointed out that my question was too vague and I should have done my research, which is constructive criticism - which I appreciate. 

This has also helped me understand the concept.